# Omnifaces httpfilter redirect issue

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Hi i have this regular javax.servlet.Filter

```
  @WebFilter(filterName = "UserFilter", urlPatterns = {"*.xhtml"})
public class UserFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String EXPIRED_PAGE = "loginPage";

    @Inject
    private transient Logger log;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        HashMap<String, Object> user = (session != null) ? (HashMap<String, Object>)     session.getAttribute("sessionParameters") : null;
        Integer userSession = (user != null ? (Integer) user.get("usuarioSesion") : null);
        boolean isLoginPage = (request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("login.xhtml") > -1);
        if (userSession != null || isLoginPage) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(EXPIRED_PAGE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {  }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {    }
}
```

after finding OmniFaces HttpFilter  im triying to implementing it

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "UserFilter", urlPatterns = {"*.xhtml"})
public class UserFilter extends HttpFilter {
    private static final String EXPIRED_PAGE = "loginPage";
    @Inject
    private transient Logger log;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, FilterChain fc) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, Object> user = (session != null) ? (HashMap<String, Object>) session.getAttribute("sessionParameters") : null;
        Integer userSession = (user != null ? (Integer) user.get("usuarioSesion") : null);
        boolean isLoginPage = (request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("login.xhtml") > -1);
        if (userSession != null || isLoginPage) {
            fc.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(EXPIRED_PAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

way cleaner code :) , the problem that im getting is that is not redirecting to my login page that i place on my faces-config navigation xml. On debug mode i can see it going to the redirect but it wont redirect any help would be appreciated (Sorry im a little new to this filter world thanks!) Oh and it works using the regular Filter

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
```

Comment: @BalusC :) i always read all your blogs and used them all the time (Love OmniFaces)thanks a lot for the replied after doing some more extensive testing, Omnifaces Httpfilter works fine, with  `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");` for ajax=false request, but when i select a row or any ajax=true component it wont redirect any input would be helpful, i used to had a phaselistener and after reading one of your [post](stackoverflow.com/questions/16192003/handlenavigation-not-working-in-phaselistener). on the subject, im trying to implement the filter

Comment: FullAjaxExceptionHandler really solves it and its pretty clean, thanks again @BalusC, added <factory> <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandl‌​erFactory</exception-handler-factory> </factory> to facesconfig.xml and <error-page> <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type> <location>/login.xhtml</location> </error-page> to web.xml also added what u posted [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html#MakeShiroJSFAjaxAware) and problem solved! thanks again